# The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to get a signed url and then upload a file, but it returns an error that I have not been able to solve, I have already seen other questions but nothing yet, I'm trying with a png file and I specified it in the cont.

[image: strong text]

```
 const fileD = storage.bucket(bucket).file(file)
      const config = {
        action: 'write',
        expires: '03-17-2025',
        ContentType: 'image/png'
      }
      fileD.getSignedUrl(config, async function Sing(err, url) {
        if (!err) {
          const options1 = {
            method: 'PUT',
            url,
            headers: {
              'cache-control': 'no-cache',
              'Content-Type': 'image/png'
            },
            data: './uploads/test.png'
          }

          axios(options1)
            .then((response) => res.json(response))
            .catch((error) => res.json(error.response.data))
        }
      })
```

Comment: I think the date/time/timezone on your computer is wrong. That will cause this error message.

Comment: my computer has today's date, if I request an image "read" it does return the url and I can see the image, but I can't PUT @JohnHanley

Comment: If the date, time, and time zone are correct then the next possibility is the HTTP PUT must match the signing request including the headers and object name. The only difference is `'cache-control': 'no-cache',`. Try removing that.

Comment: I get the same error, if I delete that line, I was also trying it in postman sending directly to the signed url and it doesn't work either. @JohnHanley

Comment: how did you manage to solve it ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is answer for your question, but for whom that might have same problem. i had same issue when i tried to deploy cloud function. Then i recognized that vpn was causing this. Closing vpn fixed it..

Answer (score -1):

You get errors on Postman because you're sending the request with `GET`. Change the request method to `PUT`.

On your code, the root cause of the problem is simply because of a typo. If you check the [docs](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#getSignedUrl) the correct property for your config should be `contentType`, not `ContentType`.

Because of the typo, `Content-Type` is not properly signed in the URL so adding this header on your request will result in a mismatch error.

Here's a fixed version of your code:

```
const fileD = storage.bucket(bucket).file(file)
const config = {
  action: 'write',
  expires: '03-17-2025',
  contentType: 'image/png'
} 
fileD.getSignedUrl(config, async function Sing(err, url) {
  if (!err) {
    const data = fs.readFileSync('./uploads/test.png') 
    const options1 = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'image/png'
      }
    }
    axios.put(url, data, options1)
      .then((response) => console.log(response.status))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error.response.data))
  }else{
    console.error(err)
  }
})
```

---

For additional reference, see `Content-Type` in https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls-v2#string-components